# A BTree implementation in python that allows duplicate keys?

Tags: python, database, b-tree

I'm trying to build a structure for indexing a database. i.e., pairing the indexed values with a pointer to the tuple. 
I found https://pythonhosted.org/BTrees/, however, the API tells me that it doesn't allow for insertion of multiple keys with different values. I find this problematic when I want to create an index on a column that isn't the primary key.

Is there a BTree implementation in python that does allow for insertion of the same keys?

Comment: Are you asking for a library implementation, or how to write your own? Unfortunately asking for a library may be off topic for this site, as we mostly want questions that have a single best answer, not ones that might have many answers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask for a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary, with the values being either a list (for duplicate values), or a set (to exclude duplicate values).